# Retrieve information from Parse Local Data Store

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

i am trying to retrieve data from parse local stat store.

i assume that it is pinning because there is no error when running the following:

```
let contact = PFObject(className: "temp")
contact["firstName"] = "steve"
contact["lastName"] = "smith"
contact["email"] = "steve.smith@example.com"
contact.pinInBackground()
```

the error comes when trying to retrieve:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "temp")
query.whereKey("firstName", equalTo: "steve")
query.fromLocalDatastore()

query.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) in

     if error == nil {
          for object in object! {
               print(object["firstName"] as! String)
          }
     }
}
```

returns this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Method requires Pinning
>   enabled.'

I've read a bit online about the call location of

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
```

in the app delegate but i haven't been able to produce any results and this template was dl direct from parse, this is the first part of my app delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


//--------------------------------------
// MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
//--------------------------------------

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
    // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "XXX"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "XXX"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "XXX"

    })

    Parse.initialize(with: parseConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted....

```
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
```

seems to be a legacy item that i got from somewhere.

simply adding:

```
ParseMutableClientConfiguration.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true
```

fixes the problem.

You will need to remove or comment out all instances of

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
```